# How to change linetype legend title in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I have a graph with a legend that contains both color and line type elements, which represent neighborhood SES and sex, respectively. I'd like to rename the title of the line type element in the legend from "SexF" to "Sex". I've tried changing the `legend.title =`  line in the following code to `legend.title = c("Neighborhood SES", "Sex")`, but the result is the same as the output below.

```
surv.model <- surv_df %>%
  ggsurvplot_df(
    surv.geom = geom_line,
    color = "exposure",
    linetype = "SexF",
    censor = FALSE,
    conf.int = FALSE,
    ylim = c(crop, 1),
    legend.title = "Neighborhood SES",
    title = "Effect of Neighborhood SES on Survival",
    xlab = "Time post-discharge (years)",
    ylab = "Survival Probability",
    surv.scale = "percent",
    break.time.by = 2,
    palette = c("#FFE082", "#FFB300", "#FF8F00", "#EF5350", "#B71C1C"),
    ggtheme = theme_classic(),
  ) +
  theme(
    title = element_text(family = "proxima", face = "bold", size = 20),
    legend.title = element_text(family = "proxima", face = "bold", size = 8),
    legend.text = element_text(family = "proxima", size = 7),
    legend.position = c(0.125, 0.325),
    axis.title = element_text(family = "proxima", face = "bold", size = 12),
    axis.text = element_text(family = "proxima", size = 10),
    text = element_text(family = "proxima")
    )
```

[image: plot with legend]

Comment: ```+ labs(linetype= "Sex", color = "Neighborhood SES")```